# Laravel retrieving data from a polymorphic relation EMPTY

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I have three tables (actors, films and categories) that use images from a four table (images)

They are in a polymorphic relation.

I want to get All films with its images.

Models

```
- Film

    class Film extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = ['name','image_id'];

        public function images()
        {
            return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'imageable');
        }
    }

- Images

    class Image extends Model
    {

        protected $fillable = [ 'image', 'imageable_id', 'imageable_type' ];

        public function imageable()
        {
            return $this->morphTo();.
        }
    }
```

The film controller is like this:

```
class FilmsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $films = Film::with('image')->get();

        return view('admin.films.index', compact('films', 'image'));
    }
}
```

But I get an Empty Image in the index.blade.php

like this:

```
Films
{
"id":1,
"name":"This is a new film",
"image_id":7,
"created_at":"2018-03-15 20:35:26",
"updated_at":"2018-03-15 20:35:26",

"image":[]
}
```

[image]

In the data base I see that the image.id 7 exist (image.jpg)

How do I get the image?

Answer (score 0):

Why in your film model dont you have something with the looks of this

```
public function image()
 {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Image', 'id', 'id_image');
 }
```

**Source**: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: Because the IMAGE model is related to FILMS, ACTORS and CATEGORIES. I am using just one table to store images for all models in the App.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations